# two div elements with one in center and another one in right

Tags: html, css

I want to position a div element centered in a page with width about 1000px and another one on its right that covers the whole   right side that can adjust depending on the window size.
Actually I have a right floated element on the centered div. So 
absolute positioning does the job but the flaw in it is visible while zooing in the page...

I want to know if it is possible using pure html, css and not javascript.

Also I have used background property, absolute positioning to achieve the above but looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my go:

**HTML**

```
​<div id="container">
    <div id="right">
        <div id="right_content">sdfdsfdfg</div>        
    </div>
    <div id="main">sdfdsfdzgf</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body { height: 100% }
#container { height: 100%; background: #ccc; }

#right {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f00;
    z-index: 0;
}

#right-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px; /* half the width of #main */
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00f; 
    z-index: 1;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/3/

Comment: It's not that what OP want because when you write the text on it then the text is hide check this http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/2/

Comment: actually i have a right floated element on the centered div and the centered div is not to have any background itself. only the floated element has background. So a problem occurs with the above code while zooming in the page...