# Menu fitting window size

Tags: html, css, background

I have a issue with my menu:
I have a div with 960px, which have a background (image 2). In the left of image 2, need another element with fitt left space, and right, a div which need to fitt right space.

So, if I have a resolution of 1024px, left need to have 32px, center (ever) 960px and right 32px. If have a resolution of 2048px, left: 544px, center: 960px, right: 544px.

```
<div id="container-menu">
    <div id="left-bg">// EMPTY, ONLY NEED TO FIT THE WINDOW LEFT //</div>
    <div id="center-bg">// HERE GO MENU AND LOGO //</div>
    <div id="right-bg">// EMPTY, ONLY NEED TO FIT THE WINDOW RIGHT//</div>
</div>
```

See image:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Image 1 and Image 3 have `1px` of width and `repeat-x` added to background

Image 2 have `960px` of width

All images are transparent png.

Thanks!

Comment: I recently answered a similar question, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9953201/825789. It uses just two columns, but you could use the same trick for three columns.

Comment: so do the left and right images need to expand, would they be repeating patterns or block colour as in your example?

Comment: @hcharge `1 x 60 px` `repeat-x`. Updating question.

Comment: @bfavaretto does not work, my images are transparent, so `z-index` are not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 **Flex** property for this.

For Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="left">1</div>
 <div class="middle">2</div>
 <div class="right">3</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    width: 100%;
}

.parent div{
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    height:40px;
}
.parent .middle{
    width:460px;
    background:yellow;
}
.left{background:red;}
.right{background:blue;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/pMh97/1/

Comment: and with css more browser friendly? Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: you can use display:table property for this which work till IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/pMh97/2/